# ui.router netsted state which defined in another module not work when refresh page

Tags: express, angular-ui-router

My app has two angular modules (hub and bApp). hub module is a container for another modules (bApp). I use ui.router for routing and config as follow as:

In hub.js (hub module) file:

```
var hub = angular.module('hub', ['ui.router', 'bApp']).config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state({
        name: 'hub',
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'hub/views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    }).state({
        name: 'hub.frontends',
        url: 'frontend',
        templateUrl: 'hub/views/frontend.html',
        controller: 'FrontendCtrl',
        resolve: {
            frontendList: function (getList) {
                return getList.getAll('/api/frontend');
            }
        }
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: true }).hashPrefix('!');
});
```

In bApp.js (bApp module) file:

```
var bApp = angular.module('bApp',[]).config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider.state({
        name: 'hub.book',
        url: 'book',
        templateUrl: 'book/views/book.html',
        controller: 'bookCtrl',
        resolve: {
           bookList: function(getList){
               return getList.getAll('/api/book');
           }
        }
    }).state({
        name:'hub.book.test',
        ulr:'book/test',
        template: '<h1>test</h1'
    });
});
```

Finally in express server, I config as follow as (just for working with html5Mode):

```
app.all('/user/*', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('static/user/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Everything works well if I only navigate between states by $state.go. But when I refresh or enter url to browser and press enter, only states which defined in hub module is work.

**States which defined in bApp module is not work**. But hub.run() still work normally, but just show a blank page with no error.

I don't know how to figure out this problem.

Thanks!